# Swift - Access self to avoid passing parameters to a function

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Let's say I have an User class with Posts:

```
class User {
 internal var id: Int
 internal var posts: Entities<Post>
}

let myUser = User()
```

Now I want to fetch all posts that belong to this user, something like:

```
myUser.posts.fetchAllForUser(myUser.id)
```

However, I want to avoid passing `myUser.id` as a parameter in `fetchAllForUser`. How can I access `myUser.id` in `fetchAllForUser`, which is implemented by `posts`?

**EDIT:**
The problem with `myUser.posts.fetchAllForUser(myUser.id)` is that the `self` in `fetchAllForUser` would be actually `posts`. *I need something like `self.self`, but `self.self` is `self` itself*, lol;-)

Moreover, the generic class `Entities<T>` conforms to `Fetchable`:

```
class Entities<Element> : Fetchable { ... }
```

Because I was asked - here is what the **intended** definition of `Fetchable` would be like:

```
protocol Fetchable {
  associatedtype Element

  func fetchAllForUser(onSuccess: () -> [Element], onError: () -> Void) { ... }
}
```

See, I don't really want to pass the user.id as a param

Comment: Could you please provide more context? What is `Element`? Are `id` and `posts` `let` constants or `var`s?

Comment: better? I've corrected the generic and specified id & posts. 
The rest you could consider as black box - exact implementation doesn't really matter.

Comment: How is `Fetchable` defined?

Comment: @appzYourLife
does that answer your question?

Comment: But this is not a valid syntax `var posts: Entities<Post> : Fetchable`

Comment: @appzYourLife do I need to provide more information? I haven't implemented anything yet, still considering how to go about it.

Comment: Can I suggest you how I would do what I think you want to do?

Comment: Yes, sure, I'm new to swift - would be happy. @appzYourLife, bear in mind that I have more entities (not only posts) such as followers, following etc - this is why a more generic implementation is needed

Comment: wait guys, I see two very good answers that are slightly different from what I want to accomplish. Let me think for a second, I'm going to post my final approach and most probably accept @kabiroberai's answer since it's closer to what I've intended.

Comment: @lustoykov I edited my answer a bit, you may want to check it out again as it wouldn't have compiled before.

Comment: @kabiroberai
don't worry, I'm more interested in the high-level idea;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to access the user with `self`, you could simply make an `EntitiesDelegate` protocol that has a variable containing the `User`'s `id`. This solution uses a common design pattern in Cocoa Touch known as delegation.

```
protocol EntitiesDelegate {
  var id: String {get set}
}
```

You would then create a reference to an `EntitiesDelegate` inside of your `Entities` class, and change the `fetchAllForUser` method's definition to have the `id` argument as nil by default. If the `id` is passed in, you can use it, but if it isn't, use the delegate's `id` instead using the Nil Coalescing Operator (note that this may be `nil` too, so maybe throw an error if both are `nil`)

```
class Entities<Element> : Fetchable {
  var delegate: EntitiesDelegate?

  func fetchAllForUser(id: Int = nil, onSuccess: () -> [Element], onError: () -> Void) {
    guard let idToUse = id ?? delegate?.id else {
      return //Maybe throw an error here
    } 
    //Use idToUse from here on
  }
}
```

You can then implement this in your `User` class by simply making it conform to the `EntitiesDelegate` protocol.

```
class User: EntitiesDelegate {
  ...
  init(...) {
    ...
    posts.delegate = self
  }
}
```

And that's it! You can now call simply call the method with `myUser.posts.fetchAllForUser()`, and since you already have an `id` variable in your `User` class, you don't even need to change anything to make it conform to `EntitiesDelegate`.

If you're trying to follow Swift 3 design patterns, you may want to change the method signature to `func fetchAll(for id: Int = nil...)` instead, which can be called with `myUser.posts.fetchAll()` or `myUser.posts.fetchAll(for: 0)` when you want to specify an id.

Comment: this is perfect, thanks! You can also suggest to rename the question, because this answer is very good and would be nice if more people saw it

Comment: @lustoykov you're welcome! Have a look at [this great WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/) for more info on Protocol Oriented Programming in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you need this is a possible solution

### Model

First of all lets define your model

```
struct Post {
    let userID: String
}

struct User {
    let id: String
    let posts: [Post]

    init(id: String, posts:[Post]) {
        self.id = id
        self.posts = posts
    }
}
```

### Dao

Next you need a class that retrieves some data from the network (e.g. in JSON format) and convert that data into a `Post`

```
final class Dao {
    static let sharedInstance = Dao()
    private init() { }

    func fetchUser(id:String, completion: (user: User?) -> ()) {

        // call webservice
        // convert NSData to JSON
        // extract id and posts from JSON
        // create User value

        // if everything goes fine then call completion(user)
        // else call comletion(nil)

    }

}
```

> I suggest you SwiftyJson and Alamofire for the Dao implementation

### Usage

Now you can write

```
Dao.sharedInstance.fetchUser("1") { (user) in
    if let user = user {
        print(user.posts)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've upvoted your answer for the effort, but see @kabiroberai - that's what answers my question:)